# Identify these two components (presumably voltage regulators) - top markings "25M 95" and "812CC"

Tags: voltage-regulator, identification, components, surface-mount

Below is a photo of the components. The PCB is 12V battery powered.
It's still actually working and I'm just looking at its circuit to get some ideas for my project.

I think the two components are both voltage regulators based on their output reading of 5V (SOT89) and 3.3V (SOT23-5) as seen on the image. But I still wanted to get their datasheets to look at the other electrical characteristics, like thermal, leakage currents and such.

What are these components? I can't find the part numbers based on those marking codes.

[image: photo of PCB showing the unknown components]

Comment: the problem is, those markings don't necessarily mean the component name; Just expect that you will never know; There are many voltage regulators on different websites that fit these descriptions; The smaller one has 3 different voltages, one of them (3.3 or 4.5) could be enable signal.

Comment: Yeah, figured it will be very difficult especially if it doesn't have any "logos" on it. Was just hoping there will be someone in here who have encountered these components and know these series of marking codes.